# Git workflow of a multi phase project in parallel

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, git-workflow, git-worktree

We are working on a project with a client which is divided into two phases. Our phase-1 just went live on production environment. Now, the situation here is we have started development for phase-2 and in parallel we are getting some change requests for phase-1 as well which includes massive features.

Can anyone suggest the ideal git workflow for this scenario, as the standard git workflow fails here. That is:

- master branch is pointing to client's PROD environment and currently possess code for phase-I
- uat branch is pointing to client's UAT environment and currently possess added features for phase-I
- develop branch is pointing to local DEV/QA office environment and we are managing all the feature branches(including phase-I and phase-II) in this.

I am open to all options. Thanks.